# Custom spinner control, data binding runtime crashes while setting adapter

Tags: android, spinner, classcastexception, android-databinding

I want to use this custom spinner with data binding, to bind entries with my list: https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner

Everything works with standard spinner, sample xml layout:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                    android:id="@+id/add_event_internal_category_spinner"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
                    android:entries="@{event.internalCategoryNames}"
                    android:prompt="@string/spinner_category_title"
                    android:selectedItemPosition="@={event.selectedInternalCategoryPosition}"
                    android:visibility="@{event.editable?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE}"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6"/>
```

However, if I try to use searchable spinner control instead of standard spinner, I'm getting an exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.databinding.adapters.ObservableListAdapter cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.ArrayAdapter

Exception is thrown while control tries to set adapter, code:

```
    @Override
    public void setAdapter(SpinnerAdapter adapter)
    {

        if (!_isFromInit)
        {
            _arrayAdapter = (ArrayAdapter) adapter; //--EXCEPTION
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(_strHintText) && !_isDirty)
            {
                ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(_context, android.R.layout
                        .simple_list_item_1, new String[]{_strHintText});
                super.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            }
            else
            {
                super.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            _isFromInit = false;
            super.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
```

`ObservableListAdapter` is package private, so it can't be used. Do you have any idea what's wrong? `SearchableSpinner` extends `Spinner` class: https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner/blob/master/searchablespinnerlibrary/src/main/java/com/toptoche/searchablespinnerlibrary/SearchableSpinner.java

Comment: what is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You get that exception, because the data binding systems standard binding adapter for `android:entries` uses and sets `ObservableListAdapter`.

In `AbsSpinnerBindingAdapter` (doesn't matter if androidx or android):

```
@BindingAdapter({"android:entries"})
public static <T> void setEntries(AbsSpinner view, List<T> entries) {
    if (entries != null) {
        SpinnerAdapter oldAdapter = view.getAdapter();
        if (oldAdapter instanceof ObservableListAdapter) {
            ((ObservableListAdapter) oldAdapter).setList(entries);
        } else {
            view.setAdapter(new ObservableListAdapter<T>(view.getContext(), entries,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, 0));
        }
    } else {
        view.setAdapter(null);
    }
}
```

So it's okay to use the `AppCompatSpinner` (and also `Spinner`) but the `SearchableSpinner` you are using expects it to be an `ArrayAdapter`.

**Solution**

You have to declare your own binding adapter, custom setter, which uses `ArrayAdapter`. You either provide your own for the `android:entries` attribute (the data binding system will use yours instead of the standard one) or you invent a new attribute name and use it in your XML (e.g. `bind:entries`).
If you don't know how, take a look [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/android-data-binding-custom-setters-55a25a7aea47).